# Prevent ox-koma-letter.el from creating .tex files?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, tex

When running `org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf` on an .org file to create a .pdf file `ox-koma-letter.el` also creates a .tex file. Does anyone know if there is any way to prevent it (or just clean it up after export)?

Comment: Prevent it? No: it's a LaTeX class, so it has to go through a LaTeX processor to get to PDF. Clean it up? Yes: you can advise `org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf` to do the cleanup. However, the .tex file is often useful for debugging, so I would think twice about automatically cleaning it up.

Comment: No worries, it just makes the directory a bit messy (I only need .org and .pdf files). I hoped that maybe .tex file could be stored in memory during the export time without saving it to disk (or perhaps stored in a temporary directory).

Comment: It could but the standard export functions all use the current directory. The latex fragment functions *do* use a temp directory and clean up - but when something goes wrong, you have to jump through hoops to convince Org to keep the temporary files so you can debug - see e.g. [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79620/how-to-locate-the-latex-fragment-equation-that-failed-org-latex-preview). There are pros and cons either way.